# Setting focus on mat button dynamically not working

Tags: angular, typescript, button, angular-material, focus

In my application I have an input field where user can enter the city code and on focus out service will be called to get the City details and search button will be enabled and focused . When the user enter the city code and tab out everything works as expected but the focus is not been set to Search button. I understand that disabled buttons will not receive focus event but am setting focus only after enabling the button but it still doesn't seem to work .

**Ts**

```
export class InputErrorsExample {
  city = new FormControl('');
  search: boolean = false;

  fetchCityDetails() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // calling service to fetch details
      this.search = true;
      let btn = document.getElementById('search');
      if (btn) btn.focus();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>City</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="city" (focusout)="fetchCityDetails()">

  </mat-form-field>

  <button tabindex="0" id="search"  mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled] = "!search">Search</button>

</form>
```

Here is the link for stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymkvhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-errors-example.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delay the focus of button with another setTimeout

```
 fetchCityDetails() { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      // calling service to fetch details
      this.search = true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        let btn = document.getElementById('search');
        if (btn) btn.focus();
      })
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response . But for some reason its not working when i try with original code . Button gets enabled after getting response from service and also based on couple of conditions . I need button to be focused as soon as it gets enabled . Can you help with that.

Comment: Sure can you please share some code example?